# Random numbers 1-6

Tags: java, android

Im trying to create a simple high/low app but the application crashes when I try to get a random number.
Here is some code:

```
final TextView counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tcounter);
Button high = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bhigh);
Button low = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blow);
Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bplay);
final Random rstart = new Random();
final int counternr = rstart.nextInt(5) + 1;

start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            counter.setText(counternr);
```

That is supposed to set the TextView "counter" to a random number from 1-6, but gives me a crash.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here is the error text:

```
11-23 20:17:40.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(765): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-23 20:17:40.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(765): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx.xxx.xxx.play}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-23 20:17:40.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(765):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
11-23 20:17:40.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(765):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
11-23 20:17:40.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(765):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-23 20:17:40.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(765):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
11-23 20:17:40.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(765):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-23 20:17:40.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(765):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-23 20:17:40.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(765):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-23 20:17:40.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(765):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-23 20:17:40.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(765):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-23 20:17:40.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(765):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-23 20:17:40.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(765):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-23 20:17:40.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(765):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-23 20:17:40.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(765): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-23 20:17:40.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(765):     at xxx.xxx.xxx.play.onCreate(play.java:26)
11-23 20:17:40.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(765):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-23 20:17:40.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(765):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
11-23 20:17:40.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(765):     ... 11 more
```

Very messy, but I hope it is OK.

Comment: Post a stacktrace or a copy of your log that shows where the crash originates and what exception its throwing.

Comment: "NullPointerException" at "xxx.xxx.xxx.play.onCreate"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change this

```
counter.setText(counternr);
```

with this

```
counter.setText(Integer.toString(counternr));
```

The method `setText` accepts only a `CharSequence` object as argument (in this case, a `String`), or an `int` if it represents a resource ID

Comment: Actually it also seems to accept an integer so you can pass a resource ID. This would explain why it's a runtime error instead of a compile time one.

Comment: Still crashing, checked the debug window and it says something about "NullPointerException" and pointing "onCreate".

Comment: I belive it is line 26 which looks like this:
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

Comment: Add to your post the stacktrace; in this way, we can help you in a very better way

Comment: See the MisterSquonk's answer, probably the problem is setContentView

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are calling `setContentView(...)` BEFORE using `findViewById(...)` for your `Buttons` and `Textview`.

If you don't they wont be found and they'll all be null. In that case, trying to set the `start.OnClickListener(...)` will throw `NullPointerException`.